# Split string on spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea where you can type in a message. After typing a '@', the messages should be splitted on spaces. After putting all the words into an array, I would like to search the array for words like this: `@person1`, `@person2`.

But the first part is already going wrong.

I tried it with the following code, but the array always seems to be empty.

```
$("textarea.autocomplete-pt").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 64) {
        var string = $(".autocomplete-pt").text(),
            array = string.split(/ +/);
        console.log(array);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ryab0po/)

Comment: Use `\s` for space characters, `array = string.split(/\s+/);`

Comment: @Tushar: I've added a jsfiddle now :) It's working. A combination of your solution and Adriano Repetti's answer did the job.

Comment: Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2ryab0po/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read content of `input` and `textarea` you have to  use `val()` instead of `text()`. Refer to jQuery documentation for further details but your code should be like this:

```
$("textarea.autocomplete-pt").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 64) {
        var string = $(".autocomplete-pt").val().trim();
        var array = string.split(/\s+/);
        console.log(array);
    }
});
```

As Tushar already suggested in comments it's also better to use `\s+` instead of    to match spaces because it also handles multiple spaces and *other kind of spaces* (tabs, short and long spaces and so on, it's especially useful if users will paste text copied from another page or they have double/single width characters in Japanese).

Comment: You should use `\s+` to split by spaces in regex

Comment: @Tushar I agree, added that.